# Ionic doesn't work build - errors that don't exist anymore

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, angular5

I am trying to `build` my Ionic app, but the terminal displays this:

```
ionic build
Running app-scripts build:
[12:46:01]  build dev started ...
[12:46:01]  clean started ...
[12:46:01]  clean finished in 16 ms
[12:46:01]  copy started ...
[12:46:01]  deeplinks started ...
[12:46:01]  deeplinks finished in 62 ms
[12:46:01]  transpile started ...
[12:46:04]  typescript: C:/Users/TOYANSK/Documents/Projects/IBeautyme/src/app/services/perfil.service.ts, line: 3
            Cannot find module '../../models/perfil'.

       L2:  import { AngularFireDatabase } from "angularfire2/database";
       L3:  import { Perfil } from "../../models/perfil";

[12:46:04]  typescript: C:/Users/TOYANSK/Documents/Projects/IBeautyme/src/app/services/perfil.service.ts, line: 14
            Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1.

      L13:  getPerfil(uid){
      L14:      return this.db.list<Perfil>('/perfil/' + this.uid);

Error: Failed to transpile program
    at BuildError.Error (native)
    at new BuildError (C:\Users\TOYANSK\Documents\Projects\IBeautyme\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\util\errors.js:16:28)
    at C:\Users\TOYANSK\Documents\Projects\IBeautyme\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\transpile.js:159:20
    at transpileWorker (C:\Users\TOYANSK\Documents\Projects\IBeautyme\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\transpile.js:107:12)
    at Object.transpile (C:\Users\TOYANSK\Documents\Projects\IBeautyme\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\transpile.js:64:12)
    at C:\Users\TOYANSK\Documents\Projects\IBeautyme\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\build.js:109:82
[12:46:04]  copy finished in 3.05 s
```

The strange part is that both errors, at lines 3 and 14, are not on my code anymore. This kind of problem occurs also if I try `run` or `serve --lab`.

When I run `serve --lab`, I see these errors on my console too:

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8100/build/main.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
vendor.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
main.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8100/build/main.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
vendor.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
main.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8100/build/main.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

My *package.json* is:

```
{
  "name": "IBeautyme",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "5.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "5.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "5.0.1",
    "@angular/http": "5.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.1",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "4.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/google-maps": "4.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "angularfire2": "^4.0.0-rc.1",
    "cordova-android": "^6.3.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.4",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^3.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-googlemaps": "^2.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^1.1.16",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.1",
    "firebase": "^3.7.5",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.2",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.2",
    "typescript": "^2.5.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-googlemaps": {
        "API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID": "AIzaXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "API_KEY_FOR_IOS": "AIzaXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {},
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run with cordova option.

```
ionic cordova build <platform>
```

Comment: The error is same or different. If the error is same remove the existing platforms, and run it.


`ionic cordova prepare`

Once prepare done, try with build.


`ionic cordova build <platform>`

Comment: When I run `ionic cordova prepare`, after had removed the platform, reproduces the same error. And yes, it was the exactly the same error.